# How to push element without activating onClick in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a simple todo list while learning ReactJS at the same time.

For each item in my todo list, they are grouped by `group`. For example, I have the group `Purchases` and `Build Airplane` as well as the time each `task` under that `group` is completed.

I'm trying to display the group names with how many tasks under that group are completed out of the total.

Then when you click a group name, the page changes to show you the individual tasks.

After hours of trying to figure out the problem, I've determined that when I'm creating the group names, the onClick that I'm passing is being called during the creation of the element.

In the parent `App` file I have

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toDoItems: null,
      uniqueGroups: null,
      currentView: "AllGroup"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    let uniqueGroups = [];
    fetch("/data.json")
      .then(items => items.json())
      .then(data => {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          if (!uniqueGroups.includes(data[i].group)) {
            uniqueGroups.push(data[i].group);
          }
        }
        this.setState({
          toDoItems: [...data],
          uniqueGroups: uniqueGroups,
        });
      })
  };

  onH2Click = (givenGroup) => {
    this.setState({
      currentView: givenGroup
    })
    console.log(this.state.currentView);
  }


  render() {
    if (this.state.toDoItems && this.state.uniqueGroups) {
      // console.log(this.state.currentView);
      return (
        <div>
          {this.state.currentView === "AllGroup" && <AllGroupView onH2Click={this.onH2Click} taskProgress={this.state.taskProgress} uniqueGroups={this.state.uniqueGroups} toDoItems={this.state.toDoItems} />}
          {this.state.currentView !== "AllGroup" && <SpecificGroupView onH2Click={this.onH2Click} />}
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return <h1>Loading</h1>
    }

  }
}
```

Then I have two Components.

`AllGroupView`

```
class AllGroupView extends Component {
  render() {
    let toDoItems = this.props.toDoItems;
    let uniqueGroups = this.props.uniqueGroups;
    let listItems = [];

    for (let n = 0; n < uniqueGroups.length; n++) {
      let completed = 0;
      let total = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < toDoItems.length; i++) {
        if ((toDoItems[i].group === uniqueGroups[n])) {
          total++;
          if (toDoItems[i].completedAt) {
            completed++;

          }
        }
      }
      listItems.push(<li key={n}><h2 className="h2" onClick={this.props.onH2Click(uniqueGroups[n])} >{uniqueGroups[n]}</h2><p>{completed} OF {total} TASKS COMPLETE</p></li>);
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Things To Do</h1>
        <ul className="custom-bullet arrow">
          {listItems}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And then `SpecificGroupView` component (it hasn't been worked on yet)

```
class SpecificGroupView extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <h1>Task Group 1</h1>
          <h2 onClick={this.props.onH2Click("AllGroup")}>ALL GROUPS</h2>
        </div>
        <ul className="custom-bullet">
          <li className="locked">
            <h2>Locked Task</h2>
          </li>
          <li className="incomplete">
            <h2>Incomplete Task</h2>
          </li>
          <li className="completed">
            <h2>Completed Task</h2>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div >
    )
  }
}
```

So I want it to look like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRH37.png

And when I click `Purchases` I want to then change the `currentView`

With the code above, the error I get is

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

And the line that is highlighted is

```
 listItems.push(<li key={n}><h2 className="h2" onClick={this.props.onH2Click(uniqueGroups[n])} >{uniqueGroups[n]}</h2><p>{completed} OF {total} TASKS COMPLETE</p></li>);
```

**I think I should be using map instead, but I'm not sure how to fit my current logic into a map.
Any ideas? and Thank you all so much!**

Comment: Try to use `onClick={() => this.props.onH2Click(uniqueGroups[n])}` instead of just `onClick={this.props.onH2Click(uniqueGroups[n])}` in your onClick functions where you use parameters. Same for the onClick function in your SpecificGroupView componenent.

Comment: @grenzbotin I think that worked? but now my onClick inside of `SpecificGroupView` doesn't do anything

Comment: Hm. But your SpecificGroupView is rendered? Do you see whether you can trigger the click?

Comment: Yeah the SpecificGroupView is rendered. So the onClick works inside the AllGroupView. When I change the onClick of the h2 with the innertext of "All Group"s to `console.log("t")` nothing happens, but when I do `() => console.log("t")` it prints t on click

Comment: So ya, it should work the same way for AllGroupView and for SpecificGroupView. 
And the way you call it in SpecificGroupView should be: `onClick={() => this.props.onH2Click("AllGroup")}`.
And in your parent it still shoul be `<SpecificGroupView onH2Click={this.onH2Click} />`

Comment: Oh! It works! @grenzbotin I appreciate it! If you wanna make an answer I'll mark it as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `onClick={this.props.onH2Click(uniqueGroups[n])}` you are directly calling the function instead of passing it.

Using ES6 arrow function:

```
listItems.push(<li key={n}><h2 className="h2" onClick={() => this.props.onH2Click(uniqueGroups[n])} >{uniqueGroups[n]}</h2><p>{completed} OF {total} TASKS COMPLETE</p></li>);
```

will solve it.